# Conical pendulum question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

**[image: Question]**

Hi, I was wondering why you get different answers when using different approaches to this question.

Using the method provided, I get the same answer but if I use trigonometry and do $T = \frac{35 \, g}{\cos \left( 30 \right)}$, I get $396.06285 \, N$ (using $g = 9.8 \, \frac{m}{s}$).
Contrarily, if I use the pythagorean theorem, I found $F_{net}$ with $\frac{m v^{2}}{r} = 196.23333 \, N$. Then, $T = \sqrt{196.2333^{2} + \left( 35 \, g \right)^{2}} = 395.16647 \, N$ (again with $g = 9.8 \, \frac{m}{s}$).

Thus, I am confused why different answers are obtained with each of the methods, even after compensating for the difference in the true value of the acceleration due to gravity.

Comment: Those answers are actually all very close to each other. The differences should be coming from the finite precision with which we state all the variables. For example, if you assume that the rope is exactly 3m long and the radius of the circle is exactly 1.5m, then the velocity is not exactly 2.9m/s, but only a little different.

Comment: So in an exam situation, if the question had required 3 s.f., which of them am I meant to use? I guess the method they used would be best as there is no imprecision of the acceleration due to gravity being rounded?

Comment: That's simple. If the question wanted 3sf, it would have given you data at least to 3sf. They have given you only 2sf here, and so the answer key is also only up to 2sf.

Comment: I don't follow. If I were to add 3 zeros after each value, I would get the same results as above but each answer would still not be correct to 5 s.f.

Comment: If you added 3 zeroes to 3.0m and 1.5m, then the velocity is 2.9147m/s and cannot be reconciled with 2.9m/s.

Comment: Physics is not math.  The underlying concept for this problem is the centripetal acceleration provided by the rope.  This means that you need to use the given formula in step b to calculate the tension.  If you use trig or the Pythagorean theorem to solve the problem, your teacher will mark your answer as wrong, EVEN IF you get the correct numerical answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the thing, the data in the question is just so ever *slightly* wrong. Let's assume everything as is given *except* for the length of the rope. We don't know that it is 3m long. And since we don't know this length we also don't know the angle that the rope makes with the vertical. Let us assume this as $\theta$.

Writing the equations using NLM we get:

$$Tsin(\theta) = \frac{mv^2}{r}$$
and
$$Tcos(\theta) = mg$$

taking their ratios gives us

$$tan(\theta) = \frac{v^2}{rg}$$

Putting the values we get $tan(\theta) = 0.5715256541$ (using g = 9.81)
This gives $\theta = 29.7490743360347^{\circ}$ (and **not** $30^{\circ}$)

It's because of this slight inconsistency that the final answers vary. (As you might have noticed, you used $\theta$ in method 1 but not in method 2.)

Coming to the final conclusion, this really shouldn't matter much since the answers have a very small difference and in an exam scenario, it would be advisable to follow the method provided in the original question since the crux of the question is to test your knowledge of centripetal acceleration.